# How to arrange tabview height without Appbar

Tags: flutter

```
            Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: TabBar(
                                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                                labelColor: Colors.black,
                                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                                indicatorWeight: 2,
                                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                controller: tabController,
                                tabs: const [
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Tab 1',
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Tab 1',
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    text: 'Tab 1',
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TabBarView(
                          controller: tabController,
                          children: const [
                            Text("Tab 1"),
                            Text("Tab 2"),
                            Text("Tab 3"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

How can I arrange the height of tabview the text part not title I want to arrange the height according to text's line numbers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
 children:
```

Add this it will work